# jQuery binding click to a link after AJAX call

Tags: jquery, bind

I'm getting furious - perhaps someone will be able to help me with this.

I need to re-bind the click to the link after AJAX call, but for some reason it doesn't want to work.

Here's my code:

```
if ($('.active').length > 0) {
    $('.active').click(function() {
        var elem = $(this);
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data) {
                elem.replaceWith(data);                                                     
            }       
        });         
        $('.active').bind('click'); return false;           
    });
}
```

Any idea?

Thanks for the responses - I've amended the code, but the problem is still there:

```
function makeActive() {
    if ($('.active').length > 0) {
        $('.active').click(function() {
            var elem = $(this);
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function(data) {
                    elem.replaceWith(data);                             
                }       
            }); 
            $('.active').live('click', makeActive);     
            return false;           
        });
    }
}


$('.active').live('click', makeActive);
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You would have to add the rebinding in the `success` handler if you want to execute it *after* the Ajax call:

```
success: function(data) {
    elem.replaceWith(data);
    $('.active').bind('click', /* some function needs to go here*/);
}
```

That said, in this case, [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) are probably better options [**update:** now that jQuery 1.7 is out, everything can be done with [`.on()`]](http://api.jquery.com/on/). This would also prevent double assignment of click handlers, in case you have other `.active` links that have not been replaced.

**Update:** Regarding your updated code: The way you are using `live` defeats its purpose. Please read its [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/). What you are doing is assigning a click handler when the the link is clicked, which means that you are adding click handlers over and over again.

This is an improved version of your code.

```
$('.active').live('click', function(event) {
    var elem = $(this);
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
     $.ajax({
         url: url,
         dataType: 'html',
         success: function(data) {
              elem.replaceWith(data);                             
         }       
     });    
     event.preventDefault();
     event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 32):

**UPDATE** on October 31, 2012

Starting from jQuery 1.7, the recommended approach is to use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) -

```
$(document).on('click', '.active', function () {
    // click handler code goes here
});
```

---

Can you try the following ?

```
$('.active').live('click', function()
{
    // click handler
});
```

Comment: @SayemAhmed figured it out. `.live(arg, fn)` is succeeded by `.on(bind, arg, fn)`. I had overlooked the fact that the optional argument parameter for `.on` is where the class or id is placed for AJAX calls. As opposed to placing before the `.on` call such as in `.live`. Another [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752321/jquery-live-vs-on-method-for-adding-a-click-event-after-loading-dynamic-ht) highlighted that the `.on` funciton must be bound to a static element with a child call.

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer because it does not require binding the events every time you load new elements, as it captures all click (or whatever) events that bubble to document and filters the ones matching the selector.

Comment: `$('.active').on('click', function () { ` wasnt working for me but this solution `$(document).on('click', '.active', function () {` worked.