# jQuery: Chaining on() when using delegation

Tags: jquery

In the old days, I used to chain calls to `live()` with great success, e.g.:

```
$(".something")
    .live("click", function(e) { ... })
    .live("change", function(e) { ... })
    .live("submit", function(e) { ... });
```

These days, `live()`, `bind()` and `delegate()` have been superseded by the shiny new `on()`.

I've tried simply replacing `live()` with `on()` which would seem obvious:

```
$(".something")
    .on("click", function(e) { ... })
    .on("change", function(e) { ... })
    .on("submit", function(e) { ... });
```

However, it's almost as obvious that this won't work when you consider how `on()` works. This from http://api.jquery.com/on/:

> "Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on()."

According to the jQuery docs, I need to bind to `document` and delegate to `.something` to handle live events. Unfortunately, this means I end up repeating my delegate selector (`.document`) if I want to replicate what I have above with `on()`:

```
$(document)
    .on("click", ".something", function(e) { ... })
    .on("change", ".something", function(e) { ... })
    .on("submit", ".something", function(e) { ... });
```

This works as expected but I'd really love to be able to chain more clearly like I do using `live()`. Am I missing something?

Comment: I believe DELEGATE supercedes LIVE and ON is merely a "mask" for normal eventing.

Comment: From the jQuery docs: "As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers." so it really is making live(), bind() and delegate() redundant.

Comment: Why the downvote? this seems like a good question to me.

Comment: What is wrong with the `click()`, `change()` and `submit()`-functions privided by the jQuery API?

Comment: @mariusnn, they are not 'live'

Comment: @mariusnn my question is to do with live events, e.g. for elements loaded via AJAX.

Comment: I see. Didn't even know that jquery had such features :S

Answer (score 90, accepted):

I believe you can do this:

```
$(document).on({
    "click" : function(e) { ... },
    "change" : function(e) { ... },
    "submit" : function(e) { ... }
}, ".something");
```

That is, use the "events-map" syntax to specify the events and their handlers, and then specify the selector to use for the delegate-style behaviour.

Comment: Yes, you sir are the winner. https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.7.2/src/event.js#L891

Comment: @nnnnnn thank you for being a truly helpful stackoverflow member by actually reading my question and giving a correct answer :)

Comment: Someone who actually read the question thoroughly before answering. An award is in order!

Answer (score 0):

`.live()` has a bunch of problems.  One of them was that it was evaluating the selector `".something"` when you ran the code, but then not using the result (e.g. wasteful) and then re-evaluating at runtime when the event occurred (like it needs to in order to work properly).

In addition `.live()` forced all dynamic events to be on the `document` object which could really slow event handling down if you had a lot of dynamic event handlers.  `.on()`, on the other hand, lets you pick a static parent that is much closer to the actual object and attach the event handler to that object so different dynamic event handlers can be attached both closer to the source and to different objects which makes their runtime performance much, much better when there are lots of event handlers.

So, you need to just live with the new way that `.on()` works as it is much more efficient.  It should be no big deal to you that you have to do a slight more retyping of the dynamic selector if you use the same form you're using now or, you can pass a map as the first parameter to `.on()` and handle multiple events in one `.on()` calls.  See the second form of `.on()` in [the jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for `.on()` for more info.

Here's a [simple explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752321/jquery-live-vs-on-method-for-adding-a-click-event-after-loading-dynamic-ht/8752376#8752376) of using `.on()` for dynamic behavior.

Comment: `$(".something", static_parent).live(...)` did let you pick a static parent, right?

Comment: yes: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.6.4/src/event.js#L1016 I understand the inefficiency of evaluating the selector, I'm not saying `live` was better than `on`.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question you want something as short as `live()`. Using `on()` you have to write a bit more, but if `.something` is being added dynamically then you have another option that also delegates the event.

```
var $div = $('<div/>', {
  'class': 'something',
   click: function () { ... },
   change: function () { ... }
})

// Already has events attached
// no need to delegate
$div.appendTo('body')
```

Comment: _"...that also delegates the event"_ - I don't think that's delegating, it's just binding the events directly at the time the element(s) are created.

Comment: Yup, I guess you're right, in any case it's another way of doing the same thing in certain situations.