# jQuery event handler not working on object inserted with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<button id="first">Click me first</button>

$('#first').click(function(){
  $('body').append('<button id="second">Now click me</button>');
});

$('#second').click(function(){
  $(this).hide();
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VnCEs/)

When `#first` is clicked, `#second` gets appended. When `#second` gets clicked, I want it to 
hide itself.

Why isn't this working?

Comment: @Dnyan `live` has been deprecated for ages, and I think removed in jQuery 1.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because `$('#second')` does not match anything when it gets executed.

Try assigning the click handler to the element before adding to the DOM:

```
$('#first').click(function(){
  var $button = $('<button id="second">Now click me</button>');
  $button.click(function() {
    // handler
  });
  $('body').append($button);
});
```

You can also use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to delegate the event if you need to 'attach' the event handler before the element exists.

Answer (score 4):

When you initiate this event handler

```
 $('#second').click(function(){
  $(this).hide();
});
```

'#second' element doesn't exist yet. Later you add the element but that element doesn't initiated with any event handler.

You can try this

```
$('#first').click(function(){
  $('body').append('<button id="second">Now click me</button>');
  // event handler will attached for already exist '#second' element
  // attach event if only #second doesn't have event yet
  if(!($('#second').data('events') != null && $('#second').data('events').click != undefined && $('#second').data('events').click.length == 1))
  $('#second').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: hmmm , if you do that click event will bind to the #second , every time you click on the #first . this scenario it seems correct but it i ncorrect

Comment: Understood. We just can add event handler checking to avoid the click event attached multiple time. I have update above.

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery `on` function.

```
$(document).on('click', '#second', function(){
  $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: Definately use .on which replaces delegate and live and which works for items added to the dom after the  dom is ready.

Answer (score 1):

use `on()`

```
$(document).on('click', '#second', function(){
  $(this).hide();
})
```

refer

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('#second').on("click",function(){
 $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: `live` is depreceated. DONT use it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752321/jquery-live-vs-on-method-for-adding-a-click-event-after-loading-dynamic-ht

Answer (score 0):

To clarify why your code is not working : During the definition of the event handling of #second that div doesn't exist. You should define the event handling after you are sure that the DOM element $("#second") is present in the page.