# JavaScript conflict in ASP.NET web control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, user-controls, conflict

folks.
I have searched in google for answers for my question, but all I could found was solutions about unique IDs of the generated HTML elements of asp.net web contros. **But that's not what I'm looking for.** What I need is a way to program the javascript of my web control in a way that it does not conflict when there are multiple instances of it in the same page.
For example, consider the following simple user control, wiche has a text box and a button, and that when the user clicks the button it shows an alert with the value of the thext box:

Now imagine we have two or more instances of such user contol. How can I make sure that the javascript will show the message of the proper text box, since their IDs will be generated dynamically and will be all be all different of each other? I know how to discover these IDs at runtime, that's not a problem. But the problem is how to program the user control so that the javascrip references only the elements of the instance to wich it makes part, just like the button in my simple user control example. If there are ten user controls, then it will be ten buttons, and of course ten text boxes. The simple alert message here begins to became a bit not very simple, I think.

But maybe it's really simple, I just don't know how. Thanks anyone who can help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you can approach this.

The one I like to use is to write the JS functions so that they don't refer explicitly to any element, but receive the element (or element ID) as a parameter. Then in the code behind of your (user) control, build a small piece of JS which just sets OnClientClick or calls jQuery (or whatever) to bind the elements together.

An example should make it clearer:

**MyUserControl.ascx**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MyUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="MyUserControl" %>
<div style="border: 1px solid gray; margin: 1em;">
    My ID = "<%= ID%>"<br />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbx" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn" Text="Alert!" />
</div>
```

**MyUserControl.ascx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var script = string.Format("ShowAlert('{0}'); return false;", tbx.ClientID);
    btn.OnClientClick = script;
}
```

**MyUserControl.js**

```
function ShowAlert(textboxId)
{
    var textbox = jQuery("#" + textboxId);
    alert(textbox.val());
}
```

**elsewhere (page, parent control, ...)**

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="MyUserControl.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <my:UserControl runat="server" ID="control1" />
        <my:UserControl runat="server" ID="control2" />
        <my:UserControl runat="server" ID="control3" />
        <my:UserControl runat="server" ID="control4" />
        <my:UserControl runat="server" ID="control5" />
    </div>
</form>
</body>
```

This way the actual JS which does the work is included only once and all necessary control ID's are passed as parameters.

Of course it is preferred to bind the functions to events using jQuery's `on()` function (or a similar mechanism depending on what frameworks you use) than to use OnClientClick, so that the markup ends up as free of JS as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use Clientidmode and attach click event handler(javascript)  to each button. Then by using javascrpt/jquery get button id and get last two digits and get corresponding text id by appending the last two digits got from button id to static text "txtEcho"

Example:

Text control:

```
 ID="txtEcho01" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"
```

Button control:

```
ID="btnEcho01" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution is to attach click event listener to the parent element and then in function callback listen for element. In this way you dont have to worry about IDs at all you can simply work based on the classes or event source type only. [Check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752321/jquery-live-vs-on-method-for-adding-a-click-event-after-loading-dynamic-ht)

Check following psudo code

```
<div class="portion" >

...
<input type="button"...>

<div/>


//jquery psudo code
$(".portion").live(function(e){
if (e.target == input){
//do action
}
});
```