# Jquery ajax php only working once

Tags: php, jquery

I have the following jQuery

```
        $("button#submit").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "process.php",
                data: $('form.contact').serialize(),
              success: function(msg){
                $("#form-content").modal('hide');                     
                $("#thanks").html(msg);
                $("#thanks").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
              },
                error: function(){
                    alert("failure");
                }
            });
        });
```

And Php

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
    $email = strip_tags($_POST['Email']);
    $sug = strip_tags($_POST['sug']);

    echo "<span class='label label-info'>Your Website has been submitted .. Thank you</span>";
}?>
```

This works the first time and displays the php echo on my page. But when I submit the form again it does not show.

Comment: Your $("#thanks") is hidden

Comment: its better if u can put this in a jsfiddle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `$("#thanks")` dom is hidden.

```
    $("button#submit").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process.php",
            data: $('form.contact').serialize(),
          success: function(msg){
            $("#form-content").modal('hide');                     
            $("#thanks").html(msg);
            $("#thanks").show();  <----------------ADD THIS
            $("#thanks").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
          },
            error: function(){
                alert("failure");
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.on()`.

```
$(document).on('click','button#submit',function(){  })
```

Comment: There is no difference between the `on('click')` and `click`.

Comment: @undefined i am afraid bro but there is....`on('click')` word as delegate and work on dynamically loaded content.

Comment: No, this not how `on` is used for event delegation, it's just a regular handler.

Comment: @undefined as far as i know its behave like i said....if i am wrong please correct me so i will not make mistake in future

Comment: `$('#staticElement').on('click', '.dynamicallyGeneratedElement', function(){})`

Comment: @undefined yes thats right....`$(document).on('click','button#submit')` will work right..??

Answer (score -1):

use like this

```
$("button#submit").live('click', function(e) {
  $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process.php",
            data: $('form.contact').serialize(),
          success: function(msg){
            $("#form-content").modal('hide');                     
            $("#thanks").html(msg);
            $("#thanks").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
          },
            error: function(){
                alert("failure");
            }
        });
    });
```

check difference here `.live` and `.on`
[jQuery .live() vs .on() method for adding a click event after loading dynamic html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752321/jquery-live-vs-on-method-for-adding-a-click-event-after-loading-dynamic-ht)