# ajax loaded content issue with chrome

Tags: ajax, jquery, delegates, load

I have a problem when I dynamically load content with the following code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
             $("#tags").keyup(function(){
                        var q = $(this).val(); 
                        $.ajax({ 
                            url: '/AnswerMedia/utilities/autoSearch/model/suggest.php?q='+q, 
                            success: function (data) {
                                $("#ajaxDiv").html(data); 

                            },
                            error: function (request, status, error) {
                            alert(request.responseText);
                        }
                    });  
            });
        });
```

After the content loads, this code was intended to trigger an event when one of the loaded div tags is clicked, but did not.

```
$(".pdiv").click(function(){
    var val = $(this).text();
    $('#tags').val(val);
    $('.mncontr').hide();
});
$("#closeSearch").click(function(){
    $('.mncontr').hide();   
});
```

Then I tried the following code:

```
$("body").delegate(".pdiv", "click", function(){
    var val = $(this).text();
    $('#tags').val(val);
    $('.mncontr').hide();
});
$("body").delegate("#closeSearch", "click", function(){
    $('.mncontr').hide();   
});
```

It works well in Firefox, but in Chrome the problem persists. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752321/jquery-live-vs-on-method-for-adding-a-click-event-after-loading-dynamic-ht) SO post:

> If you want the click handler to work for an element that gets loaded
>   dynamically, then you set the event handler on a parent object (that
>   does not get loaded dynamically) and give it a selector that matches
>   your dynamic object like this:
>
> `$('#parent').on("click", "#child", function() {});`
>
> The event handler
>   will be attached to the #parent object and anytime a click event
>   bubbles up to it that originated on #child, it will fire your click
>   handler. This is called delegated event handling (the event handling
>   is delegated to a parent object).
>
> It's done this way because you can attach the event to the #parent
>   object even when the #child object does not exist yet, but when it
>   later exists and gets clicked on, the click event will bubble up to
>   the #parent object, it will see that it originated on #child and there
>   is an event handler for a click on #child and fire your event.

Comment: Thanks you very much Greg Kramida for your help now its working fine

Comment: Soory dear Its very unexpected its were working nice but suddenly Its not working in chrom..do u have any other solution?

Comment: $("body").on("click", ".pdiv", function(){
     var val = $(this).text();
       $('#tags').val(val);
     $('.mncontr').hide();
   }); not working in chrome

Comment: Are you saying it was working in Chrome, then you did something to it, then it stopped working? Or are you saying that it never worked in Chrome at all?