# Delegated function inside ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery, delegation

I am using DataTables plugin with hidden rows, when using pagination, my click event fails without console error.

This is the function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#datatable tbody td a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var nTr = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
    if ( oTable.fnIsOpen(nTr) ) {
        /* This row is already open - close it */
        $(this).addClass('glyphicon-arrow-down');
        $(this).removeClass('glyphicon-arrow-up');
        oTable.fnClose( nTr );
    } else {
        /* Open this row */
        $(this).addClass('glyphicon-arrow-up');
        $(this).removeClass('glyphicon-arrow-down');
        oTable.fnOpen( nTr, fnFormatDetails(oTable, nTr), 'details' );
    }
});

});
```

As you can see i am using delegation, but the function is wrapped in a ready function. I'm certain this is the problem. How do i fix this?

**The above question was asked in error, please see my comment under the answer.**

Comment: you are not using event delegation!!! just using `on` to register does not make delegated event handling

Comment: $('#datatable tbody td a').on('click', function (e) {} is delegation?

Comment: no it is not, but `$('#datatable').on('click', 'tbody td a', function (e) {});` is delegated click handling

Comment: @Edward: No. `$("#datatable tbody").on("click", "td a"), ...)` would be delegation.

Comment: @Edward look at the difference in syntax

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752321/jquery-live-vs-on-method-for-adding-a-click-event-after-loading-dynamic-ht/8752376#8752376) for info on how delegation works with `.on()`.  As others have said, you are not using delegation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

As elements are added dynamically you can not bind events directly to them .So you have to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

```
$('#datatable').on('click', 'tbody td a', function (e) {});
```

Syntax

```
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
```

Below code is not `Event Delegation`

```
$('#datatable tbody td a').on('click', function (e) {
```

Comment: This is correct, the question i asked wasn't necessary i didn't take the time to look at the syntax before asking. If it helps the community differentiate the syntax i don't mind leaving this mistake available.

Comment: @Edward Leave this question as it is So that it will help somebody someday .