# Hide a popup error by clicking on it in Jquery validation engine?

Tags: jquery

I was using Jquery 1.8 version and validation engine on my page. And everything worked fine.
 [image]

When i click on the pop up it was hiding automatically. Now recently we have movesd to Jquery 1.10.3 version and using bootstrap on my page. So now I am not able to hide the popup by simple click on it. Please help how to hide each pop up individually?

Thanks

Edit:

Modified the  `$(".formError").live("click", function () {}` to

```
 $(".formError").on("click", function () {} inside jquery.validationengine.js file. Because if i used 'live' instead of 'on' causing page not to validate.
```

Comment: Found my answer here 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752321/jquery-live-vs-on-method-for-adding-a-click-event-after-loading-dynamic-ht

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should add parent class name also in it.

```
$('#parent').on("click", "#child", function() {});
```