# $(".box a").live("click" how to modify it

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-click-event

hi guys need little bit help..

i know `.live` is no more working in jQuery v1.9 is there any alternative that my below function get back working i try `.on()` and `.bind()` but did not succeed.
here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arun_/89wTX/4/)

> HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <p>There are 0 boxes</p>
    <a href="#" class="more">Add more +</a>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(".more").click(function() {
    $("#container").append("<div class='box'><a href='#'>x</a></div>");
    var count = $(".box").length;
    $("p").text("There are " + count + " boxes.");
    if(count>2){
        $(".more").hide();
    }

});

$(".box a").live("click", function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    var count = $(".box").length;
    $("p").text("There are " + count + " boxes.");
     if(count<3)
    {$(".more").show();}
});
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752321/jquery-live-vs-on-method-for-adding-a-click-event-after-loading-dynamic-ht/8752376#8752376 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752321/jquery-live-vs-on-method-for-adding-a-click-event-after-loading-dynamic-ht/8752376#8752376 for how you can use the proper form of `.on()` to replace `.live()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script code should be this;

```
$(".more").click(function() {
  $("#container").append("<div class='box'><a href='#'>x</a></div>");
  var count = $(".box").length;
  $("p").text("There are " + count + " boxes.");
    if(count>2)
     {
       $(".more").hide();
     }

  $(".box a").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
  var count = $(".box").length;
  $("p").text("There are " + count + " boxes.");
    if(count<3)
     {
      $(".more").show();
     }
  });   
});
```

here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/89wTX/12/)

Comment: Every time you add new box ($('.more').click), you add event listener to all boxes. So after adding 3 boxes in a row you have: 3 click listeners for 1st box, 2 for 2nd and 1 for 3rd. It means you run on click function ($(".box a").click) many times where it should be run once. It's not optimal solution.

Comment: Open your console, add 3 boxes and then remove first. How many console logs did you get (you should get one)? http://jsfiddle.net/89wTX/16/

Answer (score 2):

Use delegation of events for elements which are added dynamically:

http://jsfiddle.net/89wTX/11/

```
$(".more").on('click', function() {
    $("#container").append("<div class='box'><a href='#'>x</a></div>");
    var count = $(".box").length;
    $("p").text("There are " + count + " boxes.");
    if(count>2){
        $(".more").hide();
    }

});

$("#container").on("click", '.box a', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    var count = $(".box").length;
    $("p").text("There are " + count + " boxes.");
     if(count<3)
    {$(".more").show();}
});
```

When you just use on without delegation it attaches listeners once to existing elements. When you add new elements(boxes in your case) they have no listeners attached.

Answer (score 1):

TRy this
http://jsfiddle.net/devmgs/89wTX/9/

```
$(document).on("click",".box a", function() {
    console.log("removeing");
    $(this).parent().remove();
    var count = $(".box").length;
    $("p").text("There are " + count + " boxes.");
     if(count<3)
    {$(".more").show();}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use on :

```
$(".box").on("click","a", function() {...})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".box").on("click","a", function() {
   ....
});
```

reference **[on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**