# MVC Dialog Save Refreshes Table Stops Working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have been using the code from the article [ASP.NET MVC: Ajax Dialog Form Using jQuery UI](http://nickstips.wordpress.com/2011/08/11/asp-net-mvc-ajax-dialog-form-using-jquery-ui/) and it mostly works. I created a grid that lists records and each record has a link to bring up a dialog box to edit the record. After the record has been changed the save button is pressed and the grid is updated using ajax. This works great, but the problem comes after the first record save and the ajax refresh of the grid. If the link to edit the record is clicked again the dialog box doesn't come up, only the partial view is shown. I am guessing, but it appears the partial view that I am trying to bring up again doesn't recognize the parent container. Any ideas?

Display the partial view that contains the grid:

```
<div id="VehicleHold">
  @Html.Partial("_VehicleHold")
</div>
```

The partial view that makes up the dialog:

```
@using VehicleWeb.MVCHelpers

@{
    int agreementNumber = 0;
    var countData = ViewBag.VehicleHoldViewModel as System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<VehicleWeb.Model.VehicleHoldViewModel>;

    if (countData != null)
    {
        if (countData.Count() > 0)
        {
            agreementNumber = (int)countData.DefaultIfEmpty().First().AgreementNumber;

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
              <thead>
              <tr class="table-header">
                  <th>Edit</th>
                  <th>Delete</th>
                  <th>
                      Type
                  </th>
                  <th>
                      Year
                  </th>
                  <th>
                      Make/Model
                  </th>
                  <th>
                      Plate
                  </th>
                  <th>
                      VIN
                  </th>
                  <th>
                      Num Pass
                  </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
              <tbody>
           @{
               foreach (var item in (ViewBag.VehicleHoldViewModel as System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<VehicleWeb.Model.VehicleHoldViewModel>))
               {
                   <tr>
                       <td>
                           @Html.ImageDialogLink("UpdateVehicleHold", "Exposure", new { id = item.RID }, "Edit Hold Vehicle", "VehicleHold", Url.Action("RefreshVehicleHold/" + agreementNumber), Html.ResolveUrl("~/pics/edit-button.png"), "Edit Hold Vehicle", "600", "800", new { style = "text-decoration:none;" }, new { style = "text-decoration:none; border-style: none;" })
                       </td>
                       <td>
                            <div title="Vehicle Year">@item.EditType.ToString()</div>
                       </td>
                       <td>
                            <div title="Vehicle Year">@item.AutoYear.ToString()</div>
                       </td>
                       <td>
                           <div title="Vehicle Make/Model">@item.MakeModel.ToString()</div>
                       </td>
                       <td>
                           <div title="Vehicle Plate Number">@item.DistVehNo.ToString()</div>
                       </td>
                       <td>
                           <div title="Vehicle VIN">@item.IDNumber.ToString()</div>
                       </td>
                       <td>
                           <div title="Number Of Passengers">@item.NumOfPassengers.ToString()</div>
                       </td>
                   </tr>
               }
          }
            </tbody>
          </table>
        }
    }
}
```

I am new at asking questions here, so just let me know if you need to see more code.

EDIT:
I don't know if it the position of the jQuery files matters for this. I have been messing around with the position today and haven't found success. I do have the jQuery file on the main form that it used to wire up the dialog box. After the AJAX refreshes the DIV, the edit link seems to loose all knowledge about the any of the parent code. My latest theory is it could be something to do with this code. Could it be because it is in a ready block?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });

    // Wire up the click event of any current or future dialog links
    $('.dialogLink').on('click', function () {
        var element = $(this);

        // Retrieve values from the HTML5 data attributes of the link        
        var dialogTitle = element.attr('data-dialog-title');
        var dialogWidth = element.attr('data-dialog-width');
        var dialogHeight = element.attr('data-dialog-height');
        var updateTargetId = '#' + element.attr('data-update-target-id');
        var updateUrl = element.attr('data-update-url');

        // Generate a unique id for the dialog div
        var dialogId = 'uniqueName-' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)
        var dialogDiv = "<div id='" + dialogId + "'></div>";

        // Load the form into the dialog div
        $(dialogDiv).load(this.href, function () {
            $(this).dialog({
                modal: true,
                resizable: false,
                title: dialogTitle,
                closeOnEscape: false,
                width: dialogWidth,
                height: dialogHeight,
                buttons: [
                    {
                        text: "Save",
                        icons: { primary: "ui-icon-check" },
                        click: function () {
                            // Manually submit the form                        
                            var form = $('form', this);
                            if ($(form).valid()) {
                                $(form).submit();
                                $(this).dialog('close');
                            }
                        }},
                        {
                            text: "Cancel",
                            icons: { primary: "ui-icon-closethick" },
                            click: function () {
                                $(this).dialog('close');
                                $(this).empty();
                            }
                        }]
        });

            // Enable client side validation
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(this);

            // Setup the ajax submit logic
            wireUpForm(this, updateTargetId, updateUrl);
        });
        return false;
    });
});

function wireUpForm(dialog, updateTargetId, updateUrl) {
    $('form', dialog).submit(function () {

        // Do not submit if the form
        // does not pass client side validation
        if (!$(this).valid()) {
            return false;
        }

        // Client side validation passed, submit the form
        // using the jQuery.ajax form
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                // Check whether the post was successful
                if (result.success) {
                    // Close the dialog 

                    $(dialog).dialog('close');
                    $(dialog).empty();

                    // Reload the updated data in the target div
                    $(updateTargetId).load(updateUrl);
                } else {
                    alert('failure');
                    // Reload the dialog to show model errors                    
                    $(dialog).html(result);

                    // Enable client side validation
                    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(dialog);

                    // Setup the ajax submit logic
                    wireUpForm(dialog, updateTargetId, updateUrl);
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It some times happens when we keep the script in the main view it will bind the event for the first time but won't work after a postback, try moving the script in the partial view, if it doesn't work share some more code and will see what is wrong

Comment: I added the code that sets up the dialog box. Could this code be the problem?

Comment: move this  $('.dialogLink').on('click', function ()  whole function in partial view and let me know if it worked

Comment: That was the offending line, but I didn't have to move it. This works $('.dialogLink').live('click', function () { and this doesn't work $('.dialogLink').on('click', function () {. I am not sure what the difference is between "live" and "on", but I better figure it out because that is the key to make this work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: very good explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752321/jquery-live-vs-on-method-for-adding-a-click-event-after-loading-dynamic-ht