# JQuery on page load instead of click live()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a website that uses the following script:

```
//==================== EXPAND ========================//
$('a.expand').live('click',function() {

    var _hide   = $(this).attr('data-hide');

    $(this).addClass('activeSpan');
    $(this).parent().find('.details-post').slideDown(); 
    $(this).parents('li').find('.grid-reply').slideDown(); 
    $(this).parents('li').find('.spanReply').slideDown();       
    $(this).parent().find('.textEx').html(_hide); 
    $(this).removeClass('expand');

    if( $(this).hasClass( 'reply' ) )
    {
        $(this).parent().find('#reply_post').focus();
    }
});

$('a.activeSpan').live('click',function() {
    var _expand = $(this).attr('data-expand');

    $(this).addClass('expand');
    $(this).parent().find('.details-post').slideUp();
    $(this).parents('li').find('.grid-reply').slideUp();
    $(this).parents('li').find('.spanReply').slideUp(); 
    $(this).parent().find('.textEx').html(_expand); 
    $(this).removeClass('activeSpan');
});

$('.optionsUser > li:last').css({'border':'none'});
```

This is used to display data when the user clicks on "expand". Instead of this, I want the text to appear automatically. How should I change the script? I have tried changing live('click' to live('load' but this doesn't work.

The site uses: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js

Thanks in advance.

---

This is the php code:

```
<!-- EXPAND -->
<a data-expand="<?php echo $_SESSION['LANG']['expand']; ?>" data-hide="<?php echo $_SESSION['LANG']['hide']; ?>" class="expand getData" data="<?php echo $key['id']; ?>" data-token="<?php echo $key['token_id']; ?>">
<?php echo $icon; ?>
<span class="textEx"><?php echo $_SESSION['LANG']['expand']; ?></span> <?php echo $typeMedia; ?>
</a>
```

And this is the sample html:

```
<a data-expand="Expand" data-hide="Collapse" class="expand getData" data="697" data-token="0f1966ac9d8529055f9b0e09c0a58a65cdf5d5e8">                                  <span class="textEx">Genişlet</span>             </a>
```

Think of facebook or twitter, you click on expand and you get an area to reply to a post. At the moment I have to click to see the reply form, but I want that to appear by default.

Comment: Do you want it to trigger on page load instead of, or in addition to, being clicked?

Comment: I want it to trigger on page load instead of being clicked.

Comment: The couldn't you just remove the click event handlers and put the code inside a .ready() call?

Comment: how would I do that? Sorry I am a complete beginner at jquery :(

Comment: FYI, `.live()` has been removed from the later versions of jQuery.  You should switch to the dynamic form of `.on()` as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752321/jquery-live-vs-on-method-for-adding-a-click-event-after-loading-dynamic-ht/8752376#8752376

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom event or simply trigger the click programmatically:

```
$(function(){//run on page load

    $('a.expand').live('click',function() {

        var _hide   = $(this).attr('data-hide');

        $(this).addClass('activeSpan');
        $(this).parent().find('.details-post').slideDown(); 
        $(this).parents('li').find('.grid-reply').slideDown(); 
        $(this).parents('li').find('.spanReply').slideDown();       
        $(this).parent().find('.textEx').html(_hide); 
        $(this).removeClass('expand');

        if( $(this).hasClass( 'reply' ) )
        {
            $(this).parent().find('#reply_post').focus();
        }
    });

    $('a.activeSpan').live('click',function() {
        var _expand = $(this).attr('data-expand');

        $(this).addClass('expand');
        $(this).parent().find('.details-post').slideUp();
        $(this).parents('li').find('.grid-reply').slideUp();
        $(this).parents('li').find('.spanReply').slideUp(); 
        $(this).parent().find('.textEx').html(_expand); 
        $(this).removeClass('activeSpan');
    });

    $('a.expand').trigger("click");//trigger click on page load

    $('.optionsUser > li:last').css({'border':'none'});
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work.
The php file this references to is:

'<a data-expand="<?php echo $_SESSION['LANG']['expand']; ?>" data-hide="<?php echo $_SESSION['LANG']['hide']; ?>" class="expand getData" data="<?php echo $key['id']; ?>" data-token="<?php echo $key['token_id']; ?>">
<?php echo $icon; ?>
<span class="textEx"><?php echo $_SESSION['LANG']['expand']; ?></span> <?php echo $typeMedia; ?>
   </a>'

Anything I should change here too maybe?

Comment: hmm should not be a problem on the server side if the click was working no reason this shouldn't. You only want the function on a.expand to run correct? Do you still want to keep the click behaviour?

Comment: Yes correct. There is an expand button and collapse button. I want the expand (a.expand) to work automatically without clicking, but the collapse (a.activeSpan) to work on clicking.

Comment: Could it be because the site uses jquery 1.7.2?

Comment: are the link loaded via ajax or they're already there on page load?

Comment: ok try undo the changes and trigger a click instead $('a.expand').trigger("click");

Comment: ok can you provide a sample of html? share on your post please. I'll make a working demo with 1.7.2

Comment: that's only the link what about the elements that are being expanded?

Comment: ok nevermind I think i figured it out, you need to wrap your code with $(function(){}); so the trigger() can execute when the click event is actually available (on page load). I've updated my reply with the changes.

Comment: This didn't work on its own, but I added <script>$('a.expand').trigger("click");</script> to the html code and that did the trick! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you move the code from the anonymous function you're binding to `a.expand` to a named function, all you would need to do is invoke it on DOM ready, then you would also just pass  the function to your `a.expand` handler.

```
$(function(){
  $('a.expand').live('click', Expand);

  Expand(); // Invoke function

  $('a.activeSpan').live('click',function() {
    var _expand = $(this).attr('data-expand');

    $(this).addClass('expand');
    $(this).parent().find('.details-post').slideUp();
    $(this).parents('li').find('.grid-reply').slideUp();
    $(this).parents('li').find('.spanReply').slideUp(); 
    $(this).parent().find('.textEx').html(_expand); 
    $(this).removeClass('activeSpan');
  });

  $('.optionsUser > li:last').css({'border':'none'});
});
//Extracted function
function Expand() {

var _hide   = $(this).attr('data-hide');

$(this).addClass('activeSpan');
$(this).parent().find('.details-post').slideDown(); 
$(this).parents('li').find('.grid-reply').slideDown(); 
$(this).parents('li').find('.spanReply').slideDown();       
$(this).parent().find('.textEx').html(_hide); 
$(this).removeClass('expand');

if( $(this).hasClass( 'reply' ) )
{
    $(this).parent().find('#reply_post').focus();
}
}
```