# If else statements both getting executed in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a checkbox ".invalidDropChk" and when I click on it I want its child checkboxes to get clicked. That part is working fine. I have a "All" checkbox too. I want to check it if the other checkbox in the page ".invalidOffensive" is checked too. But the problem is that it is entering in both if and else part in the end and my checkbox "All" gets checked. Here is the code :

```
$('.invalidDropChk').live('click',function(){   
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            $(this).next().find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked',true);         
            $(this).attr('checked',true);
            var rad1 = document.getElementById("invalidDropChk");
            if(rad1 != null && rad1.attributes['checked'])
                rad1.checked = true;

        }
        else
        {
            $(this).next().find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked',false);
            $(this).attr('checked',false);
            var rad1 = document.getElementById("invalidDropChk");
            if(rad1 != null && rad1.attributes['checked'])
                rad1.checked = false;
        }

        if (($(this).is(':checked')) && ($('.invalidOffensive').is(':checked'))){
            $('.check-all ').prop('checked',true);          
        }
        else{
            $('.check-all ').prop('checked',false);
        }   

    });
```

The jsp page code is:

```
<ul class="invalidDrop">
                <c:choose>
                  <c:when test="${invalidDropForm.invalidStreetAddress==true && invalidDropForm.invalidSubName==true && invalidDropForm.derogatoryNames==true && invalidDropForm.businessNames==true && invalidDropForm.offensiveNames==true}">
                     <li><input type="checkbox" class="check-all" checked /> All</li>
                  </c:when>
                  <c:otherwise>
                     <li><input type="checkbox" class="check-all" /> All</li>
                  </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>
                <li>
                    <c:choose>
                      <c:when test="${invalidDropForm.invalidStreetAddress==true && invalidDropForm.invalidSubName==true}">
                           <input type="checkbox" class="check-inside invalidDropChk" id="invalidDropChk" checked /> Invalid Name/Address
                      </c:when>
                      <c:otherwise>
                         <input type="checkbox" class="check-inside invalidDropChk" id="invalidDropChk" /> Invalid Name/Address
                      </c:otherwise>
                    </c:choose>
                    <ul class="inneritem">                      
                        <li><sf:checkbox path="invalidStreetAddress"/> Invalid Street Address</li>
                        <li><sf:checkbox path="invalidSubName" /> Invalid Sub Name</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <c:choose>
                      <c:when test="${invalidDropForm.derogatoryNames==true && invalidDropForm.businessNames==true && invalidDropForm.offensiveNames==true}">
                           <input type="checkbox" class="check-inside invalidOffensive"  id="invalidOffensive" checked/> Offensive, Derogatory, Business Names
                      </c:when>
                      <c:otherwise>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="check-inside invalidOffensive" id="invalidOffensive"/> Offensive, Derogatory, Business Names
                      </c:otherwise>
                    </c:choose>
                    <ul class="inneritem">
                        <li><sf:checkbox path="derogatoryNames" /> Derogatory Names</li>
                        <li><sf:checkbox path="businessNames" /> Business Names</li>
                        <li><sf:checkbox path="offensiveNames" /> Offensive Names</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well? Also, do you have a minute to talk about [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: @cr0ss yes posted the jsp part of it... never used JSFiddle.. Please explain more..

Comment: I hope you realize that `.live()` is long since deprecated and even removed from recent versions of jQuery.  The [dynamic form of `.on()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752321/jquery-live-vs-on-method-for-adding-a-click-event-after-loading-dynamic-ht/8752376#8752376) can replace it.

Comment: Actually if I use .on everything stops working...

Comment: @DeepikaSethi Sure. It's a website that you can post some code, include js libraries to show other people. It is very useful to help us understand your problem.

Comment: @jfriend00 : In my case I will use $('invalidDrop').on('click','.invalidDropChk',function() if I replace live() with all() right?

Comment: @cr0ss : In JSFiddle it doesn't work fine... http://jsfiddle.net/deepikasethi/32rPW/1/

Answer (score 0):

in text: ... if the other checkbox in the page **".invalidOffensive" is not checked**

in code: ... && ($('.invalidOffensive')**.is(':checked')**)

Comment: I think I confused that.. I want to check "All" if both current and checkbox .invalidOffensive is checked....