# How to remove class after it been added

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I need a little bit of help. I'm playing around with `addClass` and `removeClass` and I can't seem to remove a class after it's set. What I basically want is:

1. When someone clicks an `h3`, it adds to its parent `div` class
2. When someone clicks a `div` with added class, class needs to be removed

First step I got out of way and it's working

```
$(function(){
    $('div h3.itemTitle').on('click', function(){
        $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

Now when I define:

```
$(function(){
    $('div.active').on('click', function(){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

It does nothing, as if it doesn't see classes. It sets only those set in `onload`...

Help, anyone?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8752376/125816

Comment: As indicated in the duplicate, that form of `on` only works with elements that are in the DOM at the time it executes. You should use the form that attaches to a parent element of the ones that should be affected and monitors changes in the DOM inside itself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery .live() vs .on() method for adding a click event after loading dynamic html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752321/jquery-live-vs-on-method-for-adding-a-click-event-after-loading-dynamic-ht)

Comment: try to add some parent id or class of the active div

Comment: I'm not sure that link answers my particular question since I'm looking for solution, not necessary with .on('click'), but any solution that will work for me.

Comment: What about `$('h3.itemTitle').parent().on('click', function(){$(this).removeClass('active'))};`? Kinda long-winded, I know.

Comment: Tried that, but no avail...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The child element "h3.itemTitle" already had a click event listener on it and the parent can't actually capture the click event.

Your $('div.active').on('click', ...) never actually fires because you click the h3 not the div.

I recommend this approach: http://jsfiddle.net/c3Q6Q/

```
$('div h3.itemTitle').on('click', function () {
    // saves time not to write $(this).parent() everything so i store in a _parent var
    var _parent = $(this).parent();

    if (_parent.hasClass('active')) {
        _parent.removeClass('active');
    } else {
        _parent.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

Comment: **THAT IS IT, I AM SOOOOOO THANKFUL!**

Comment: Glad i could help. There's no issue with "on", "live" and such, just the click target.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 $('body').on('click','div.active', function(){$(this).removeClass('active');});
```

Instead of

```
$('div.active').on('click', function(){$(this).removeClass('active');});
```

Comment: Where's the explanation? Why?

Comment: And what about "(1) When someone clicks onto h3 it adds to it parent div class"?

Comment: h3 click will work as coded by you, because of the concept of 'future element' which are added or modified after the DOM load.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with this way:

```
$('div').on('click', function(e){
    var el = e.target;
    if($(el).is('h3') && $(el).hasClass('itemTitle')){
       $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    }else if($(el).is('div') && $(el).hasClass('active')){
       $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why every is talking about elements generated outside of the initial DOM load.

Here's a JSFiddle showing that it works: http://jsfiddle.net/H25bT/

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.itemTitle').on('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    });

    /* $('.parent').on('click', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    }); */

    $('.clicky').on('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

The reason it's not working for you is that if you put the removeClass click event on the parent div itself, clicking on the child text causes a conflict with which click handler to use, and it won't work out. Code works fine if you don't assign the click to the parent div itself.