# jQuery stops listening for clicks after rendering elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I am building a smartphone app using `localStorage`. Everything works well until I make an action. Here's the JS:

```
var ls = localStorage,
    $input = $('#add-movie'),
    $content = $('.content'),
    $tools = $('.tools');

var movy = {
    // returns the next id 
    // prev id is stored in ls
    nextId: function() {
      var i = ls.getItem('index') || 0;
      i++;

      ls.setItem('index', i);
      return i;
    },

    getRelease: function(name, cb) {
        cb('12/4'); // only temporary
    },

    // adds a new movie to the localStorage
    new: function(name) {
        var data = {
            name: name
        };

        movy.getRelease(name, function(results) {
            data.release = results;
        });

        ls.setItem(movy.nextId(), JSON.stringify(data));
    },

    // show all films
    renderAll: function() {
        $tools.hide();
        var html = '';

        for (var i = 1; i < ls.length; i++) {
            var item = JSON.parse(ls.getItem(i));
            if (!item) { }
            else
                html += '<tr data-index="' + i + '"><td class="name">' + item.name + '</td><td class="date">' + item.release + '</td></tr>';

        }

        $content.html(html);
    },

    remove: function(key) {
        ls.removeItem(key);

        for (var i = key + 1; i <= ls.length; i++) {
            var item = ls.getItem(i);
            ls.setItem(i - 1, item);
        }

        // decriment i
        var index = ls.getItem('index');
        index--;
        ls.setItem('index', index);
    }
}

$(function() {
    movy.renderAll();

    $('form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        movy.new($input.val());
        console.log($input.val());

        movy.renderAll();
        console.log('rendered');
    });

    $('.content tr').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('checked');
        $tools.toggle();

        $tools.find('#trash').attr('data-index', $(this).attr('data-index'));
    });

    $('#trash').click(function() {
        var i = $(this).attr('data-index');
        console.log(i);
        movy.remove(i);
        movy.renderAll();
        // now nothing works until page is refreshed
    });
});
```

Now, at the very first time when I refresh the page, it responds to clicks, shows the toolbar when needed and everything is great.
 However, after I click on trash, and it successfully deletes that item and re-renders all the elements, suddenly jQuery stops listening for clicks, and the whole thing becomes not responsive. That is, until I refresh the page. 
Thanks!

Comment: Try using .on() method to call event

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: If you are rebuilding all the DOM elements (e.g. making new DOM elements), then your event handlers were bound to the old DOM elements and there are no event handlers on the new DOM elements.  You have to either use delegated event handling (attaching event handlers to static parent objects) or assign new event handlers to the newly create DOM elements.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752321/jquery-live-vs-on-method-for-adding-a-click-event-after-loading-dynamic-ht/8752376#8752376) for how to do delegated event handling.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks! That actually solved it. I do have other problems with deleting elements from `localStorage`. The solution I have here is not solid. Do you have ideas about that? `removeItem()` on it's own is not good.

Comment: What's the problem with `removeItem()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making my comment that solved the problem into an answer:

If you are rebuilding all the DOM elements (e.g. making new DOM elements), then your event handlers were bound to the old DOM elements and there are no event handlers on the new DOM elements.

You have to either use delegated event handling (attaching event handlers to static parent objects) or assign new event handlers to the newly create DOM elements. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752321/jquery-live-vs-on-method-for-adding-a-click-event-after-loading-dynamic-ht/8752376#8752376) for how to do delegated event handling.