# How to transfer a jquery object to the "On" method（the second params）?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I need to instead of the "Live" event in Jquery,so I must to modify my js code. But I come a problem. that is :

jquery api is : `on(events,[selector],[data],fn)`

But my code has some jquery object,like this:

```
var $obj=$(".btn");
$obj.live("click",function(){
.....................
});
```

so I change it:

```
var $obj=$(".btn");
$(document).on("click",$obj,function(){
.............................
});
```

the result is when I click dom ,the "click" event runing .....

Thx,my English is not good.forgive me

**I have solved it ,thx for friends.  "$("").selector" is a String**

var $obj=$(".btn");
$(document).on("click",$obj.**selector**,function(){
    ....................
});

Comment: You forgot to use `.on()`.  As in you forgot to type in the two letters 'o' and 'n' after the period.

Comment: You can't pass a jQuery object as the selector for the dynamic elements as it's really just a filter.

Comment: The real question is why do you need to, if you already have the elements in a variable ?

Comment: Your meaning is the "On" must to pass a "String" as selector? Can't pass a jquery selector object? if that ,I have no way to modify my js code ,because the js code use so many jquery object with "Live" event.

Comment: I'd suggest you read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752321/jquery-live-vs-on-method-for-adding-a-click-event-after-loading-dynamic-ht/8752376#8752376) about switching to `.on()` from `.live()`

Comment: Yeah ha ha,but I need thx for stackoverflow's friends ,this post is my first post in the foreign website.

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn', function() {

});
```

or if you already have the elements in a variable, you don't need delegated event handlers

```
$obj.on('click', function() {

});
```

You can't pass a jQuery object as the second parameter to `on()`, it's really just a filter that accepts a valid selector string.

Comment: Because my ".btn" is dynamic elements. It can "add" or "del" auto

Comment: But then it's not in `$obj` as that variable holds a collection of elements, not elements that can be added in the future.

Comment: Your meaning is the "On" must to pass a "String" as selector? Can't pass a jquery selector object? if that ,I have no way to modify my js code ,because the js code use so many jquery object with "Live" event.

Comment: Yes, the second argument is a filter to catch dynamic elements by targeting the non-dynamic elements, and it has to be a string. What would be the point of referencing a variable with elements, when the dynamic elements aren't in that variable.

Comment: That's one way to go, but `$().selector` is not part of the documented API and can be changed at any time, so it's not really safe to use, but it works, and has worked for years.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $obj=$(".btn");
$(document).on("click",$obj,function() {  // ".on" is missing
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thx for your remind,I write in stackoverflow miss only ...I have fixed it . thank you.