# Angular JS: load custom javascript file in ng-view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, dynamic-loading

I am using `Angular Js` for front-end of my sample, created a template and loaded views dynamically according to requirement. I am using `angular`, `jquery` and `cusotm js` for my sample application. My templates worked fine and basic structure is as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  ---------------- bootstap, css etc ----------- stylesheet include
  <script src='assets/js/angular.min.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <div ng-view></div>
</body>

-------------------- jquery, bootstrap ---------- javascript include
<script src='lib/angularjs/angular-route.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='lib/angularjs/custom-function.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

When the application runs, all my script and style-sheets are loaded successfully. But in my `custom-function.js`, I am using, elements `id` and `classes` for performing some work. When the `custom-function.js` loaded there are no document structure is defined, because the document is loaded dynamically using `<div ng-view></div>`.

I am also trying to include `<script src='lib/angularjs/custom-function.js' type="text/javascript"></script>` in my document, which is dynamically loaded by angular, but  `custom-function.js` function is not running.

I am new in angular, I searched google, but still not find any appropriate solution. how could I solve this?

Comment: You custom-function.js should be a controller, directive or service inside angular, otherwise it's going to be hard to make it work. You should 'translate' you jquery code in an angular way of programming

Comment: You can put the related script tag `<script src='lib/angularjs/custom-function.js' type="text/javascript"></script>` to end of your view template which loaded in ng-view.

Comment: Hello @nerezo, we already try this, the script is loaded, but not working

Comment: @harmeet-singh-taara can you provide an example about what code is in your custom script?

Comment: @nerezo the method like `$(document).ready(function() { }` function for documents elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With helps of ngRoute a template can be loaded which is containing a script tag which includes the js file contains javascript codes that we wanted to run.

Please take a look the below example for usage:

http://embed.plnkr.co/AonatjhKlPMaOG6vVWW1/preview

Comment: thanks for your help, the `$(document).ready(function() { })` function work fine, but my elements events are not bind. After seaching google, mostly developers say that, use `$(window).load(function() { })` instead of document, because your elements are not loaded properly, but in document function i am also find the element object successfully. In my `custom js` file, when i use `$(window).load(function() { })`  this will not work. how i can do this?

Comment: when i trying to access `alert($("#element))`, this is show the object. But when i trying to access `alert($("#element)[0])` this is show `element undefine`, in `$(document).ready(function() { })` function.

Comment: Hi @HarmeetSinghTaara, I updated the plnkr script above. I can select a field from between the body tag and from the other loaded template successfully. And also I can change values or styles of them and bind methods.

As I see, you had forgot a quote char on your selector `alert($("#element))` after the **#element**.

Comment: new problem i face is that, when my page is load, the images are fetch from another server and it takes time. that's why, my events in `$(document).ready(function() { })` are not bind. If i but these events on delay, they work properly.

Comment: @HarmeetSinghTaara please take a look below link for dynamic event binding:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752321/jquery-live-vs-on-method-for-adding-a-click-event-after-loading-dynamic-ht

Comment: you example is really good. but the problem is that, our element object is found but events are not register. if we use `delay 1500`,  then events register successfully.

Answer (score 0):

This sample might help you to find some solution using 'ngRoute' module to load what you want to show in your 'ng-view' you can give your instructions in .js file.

```
    <script src="yourinstruction.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body ng-app='base'>


    <div ng-view></div>

    <script>

   var router = angular.module('base', ['ngRoute']);

    router.config(['$routeProvider',
      function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/home.html',controller:'test'
          }).otherwise({

            redirectTo: '/'
          });
      }]);


    </script>
    <!--other codes-->
```

yourinstruction.js file

```
  router.controller('test',function ($scope) {
    <!--your instructions-->
     })
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue using '$viewContentLoaded' as shown in this tutorial:
http://www.aleaiactaest.ch/2012/06/28/angular-js-and-dom-readyness-for-jquery/

Another way is by dependency injection (the Angular way). The first part of this tutorial show us how to include an external lib by using dependecy injection.
http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/d3-on-angular.html