# Toggle close click outside

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `Toggle` I want to hide if user click out side

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#hideshow').live('click', function(event) {        
             jQuery('#header-search').fadeToggle(2000);
        });


    });

    </script>
```

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: if i click out side its not closing

Comment: what version of jquery are you using? `live()` is not supported in latest versions

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: use `on()` instead as you are using jquery 2.1.1. Please refer this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/8752376/4719761