# master page referencing javascript is not working in visual studio

Tags: javascript

I have this code In my MasterPage.master

```
<head runat="server">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%# ResolveUrl("~/") %>script.js" ></script>

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="handle">Click me</div>

</body>
```

I have this code in my script.js file

```
$('.handle').on('click', function () {
   alert('hello world');
});
```

When I click the div section, I don't have alert message as i am supposed to have. 
I have this code in my Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

 <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
 </asp:Content>

 <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="mainContent" Runat="Server">
 </asp:Content>
```

This is my project directory in visual studio

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You execute your JavaScript before the DOM is created. Change your script.js code to

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.handle').on('click', function () {
    alert('hello world');
  });
});
```

jQuery [live/on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752321/jquery-live-vs-on-method-for-adding-a-click-event-after-loading-dynamic-ht) only works after loading of the DOM is finished. As an alternative put your JavaScript code after the div-declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code and it seems to be fine to me. Let me share with you that code.

MasterPage.master:

```
            <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head runat="server">
                <title></title>
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </head>
            <body>
                <form id="form1" runat="server">
                <div>
                    <div class="handle">Click me</div>
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </div>
                </form>
            </body>
            </html>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $('.handle').on('click', function () {
                    alert('hello world');
                });
            </script>
```

Default.aspx:

```
            <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

            <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
            </asp:Content>
            <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
            </asp:Content>
```

Comment: should I have the <script></script> in MasterPage.master? or is there any other way to use "script.js" file?