# jQuery live() - alert() works but not addClass

Tags: jquery, click, live

This code works with jQuery 1.7.2:

```
    $('.category').live('click', function() {
        alert('clicked');
    });
```

But when I switch to use addClass, no class is added:

```
    $('.category').live('click', function() {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
```

Can anyone advise as to why and how to use live() to do this? Thanks.

---

Update:
I switched to the 2.2.4 version of jquery and changed the live() function for the on() function. The alert works when I target either a link created dynamically or a DOM element that is not dynamically created. However, the addClass() only works when I target an element that was *not dynamically created, and the inspector shows the active class is added for those elements, but not added to the dynamically created links.

Comment: What is the purpose of using `live` when you can use `on` ?

Comment: `live()` acted like a delegate prior to 1.9 when it was removed.

Comment: I feel this should give you some more Insight: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752321/jquery-live-vs-on-method-for-adding-a-click-event-after-loading-dynamic-ht

Answer (score 0):

As quoted in MDN Docs:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use
>   .delegate() in preference to .live().

As the method is deprecated so its functionality could have been broken for some case. You should use `.on` for binding any events to the element.

```js
$('.category').on('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="category">Some Content</div>
```

Comment: I switched jquery to 2.2.4, and switched out the live() function for on(). The alert still works, but for whatever reason it will not do addClass. Aaagh!

Comment: @jamie how are you so sure that the class is not getting added? Did you inspect the element? Does you class has some CSS styles?

Comment: Yes, I inspected the element and no class is added. I tested it by changing .category to a parent class that is not dynamically added, and the "active" class gets added (shown in inspector).

Comment: @jamie can you upload a screenshot of your code somewhere and comment here the link?

Comment: This is the code that works: $('.textwidth').on('click', function() {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });   // The only difference is if I put a dom element that is dynamically generated, no class is added.

Comment: The code works as long as the content is not dynamically generated. It's stops working as soon as I target a class that is dynamically generated.

Comment: Try this `$(document).on('click', '.category', function() { $(this).addClass('active'); });`

Comment: It alerts, but there is no "this" to add the class to.