# Adding click to jquery created dynamic ajax buttons doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have written code in javascript the function `searchCompany` queries the database and adds a list of `applicant_original` and corresponding buttons to select them. The list and the buttons are created and visible in the UI but the event handler is unable to be attached to the button.

```
function searchCompany() {
    $("#search-result").html('');
    let res = [];
    let name = $("#company_name").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: `http://localhost:5000/manualharmonization/query?name=${name}`,
        success: function (data) {
            data.map((el, i) => {
                $("#search-result")
                    .append(`<tr class="list-item"><td>${el.applicant_original}</td>
                    <td class="elem-button"><button class="button" id="${i}"type="button">Select</button></td>
                    </tr>`);


            });
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log(e);
            alert(JSON.stringify(e));
        }
    });



}

$("#search-company").click(searchCompany);

(function addClick() {
    $("tr").map(i => {
        $(`#i`).click(function () {
            console.log("clicked");
        })
    })
})();
```

The `addClick` function is not working. No button having `id=i` logs when clicked.

Comment: since you add those element dynamically use event delegation use `.on()` and bind the event on an element hat is static on load [good example to look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery .live() vs .on() method for adding a click event after loading dynamic html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752321/jquery-live-vs-on-method-for-adding-a-click-event-after-loading-dynamic-ht)

Comment: also additional suggestion use class instead of ID to make it easier for you to create the click event use this context to determine the click element.

Comment: I changed `addClick` to follows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is DOM Event delegation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation)

Comment: I changed `addClick` to follows 
   ` (function addClick() {

        $("#search-result").on("click", "button", function () {
            $(`${event.srcElement.id}`).toggleClass("submitted");
        })
    })();`
Still not working

Comment: console.log is working inside the function but jQuery is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by the following way.

```
function searchCompany() {
$("#search-result").html('');
let res = [];
let name = $("#company_name").val();
$.ajax({
    url: `http://localhost:5000/manualharmonization/query?name=${name}`,
    success: function (data) {
        data.map((el, i) => {
            $("#search-result")
                .append(`<tr class="list-item"><td>${el.applicant_original}</td>
                <td class="elem-button"><button class="button" id="${i}"type="button">Select</button></td>
                </tr>`);
    SuccessEvents();  // Add events to this functions


        })
    }
    error: function (e) {
        console.log(e);
        alert(JSON.stringify(e));
    }
})
}
$("#search-company").click(searchCompany);

function SuccessEvents(){               

  (function addClick() {
    $("tr").map(i => {
       $(`#i`).click(function () {
          console.log("clicked");
       })
     })
  })()  

}
```

Comment: This may be the answer, but adding an explanation would greatly increase the quality of your answer.  What did you do, and why do you think it will help? *Explain* your answer, so future visitors of all skill levels can learn from it.  [Code-only answers are considered low quality on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers).