# jQuery events not fired on loaded html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Got a html page with a frequently changing part. That part is read by a script on the page:

```
<script>
  console.log('In HTML');
  fetch('changes/changes.html')
    .then(data => data.text())
    .then(html => document.getElementById('changes').innerHTML = html);
</script>
```

That works fine and makes publishing changes easy. However jQuery actions (in a separate script) on the read part don't work. The events are not triggered. How to fix that?

```
$(function () {
  console.log('In script');

   $('.change-card > .change-btn-action').on('click', function () {
     console.log('Click event');
   });
)};
```

The click event is never triggered. The log order is: In HTML, In script.
Thanks for any help!
Gerard

Comment: Is the `.change-btn-action` coming from the fetch html? Do you see the console.log("In script") ?

Comment: Please post your HTML too

Comment: Yes the .change-btn-action coming is from the fetch html. I do see the "In script"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery .live() vs .on() method for adding a click event after loading dynamic html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752321/jquery-live-vs-on-method-for-adding-a-click-event-after-loading-dynamic-ht)

Comment: [Understanding Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach an event handler on body tag or parent of the dynamic element in the page and pass the dynamic element as a selector.

```
 $('body').on('click', '.change-card > .change-btn-action', function () {
     console.log('Click event');
 });
 // or
 $('#changes').on('click', '.change-card > .change-btn-action', function () {
     console.log('Click event');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('body').on('click','.change-btn-action', function () {
     console.log('Click event');
});
```