# jquery cluetip is not working when data is loaded from ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cluetip

I'm using the jquery cluetip plugin and it is working fine. The problem is that when page is loaded from ajax and I want to use cluetip on any element of this page then it is not working.

I already  call .cluetip() function on ajax loaded page.

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842119/jquery-binding-click-to-a-link-after-ajax-call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to initialise the plugin when you load the page via AJAX. Put your initialization code in the AJAX success callback.