# .submit doesn't work if the bind object was refreshed by ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, jquery

I [AJAXified commenting system](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/ajaxify-wordpress-comments/) so when `Post Comment` button is clicked ajax call is made instead of the original form submission. It works fine till I refresh the page with the comment submit button by ajax. Let's say that I only refresh the div that contains the post and comments and the button. After that the ajax is not triggered rather the original way of submitting is used.

The javascript to submit the form looks like

```
jQuery('document').ready(function($){
    var commentform=$('#commentform'); // find the comment form

    commentform.submit(function(){
//  $('#commentform').submit(function(){
```

I tried to use `$('#commentform')` instead of the variable which didn't help.

I tried to assign the commentform variable again after the successful ajax that loads new post. That didn't help either.

Part of the javascript that loads post via ajax

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(".mhomepage_item").bind("click", function(){ //bind a click event on a class with name = mhomepage_item

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: mhomepage.ajax_url,
            data: { 
                action: "get_post", 
                type: $(this).attr('type'), 
                current_post_id: $('#post_container').attr('current_post_id')
                },
            success: function(response) {
                response_from_json = JSON.parse(response);

                $('#content_container').html(response_from_json['html']);
                commentform=$('#commentform');
     }
    });

    // }
});
```

Could someone suggest how to make the `bind` to form submit button permanent even after the button is reloaded via ajax?

Comment: Any HTML to go along with this would be rather helpful...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try event delegate:

```
$(document).on("submit","#commentform",function(){
    // action to perform after submit intent
});
```

By using delegated event handler, you can handle dynamically created elements easily without having to do something like rebinding event handler.

You could also bind the event to the `body` or the closest container ***that's available when you call the function*** to avoid bubbling more levels to `document`. You could also try this in your case:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#content_container').on("submit","#commentform",function(){
        // action to perform after submit intent
    });
});
```

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: +1 I was about to post my answer just like that. Just a note : `.on()` requires jQuery 1.7+

Comment: second note: you could replace `$(document)` by `$("body")` or the closest parent selector of the form.

Comment: @JFK: actually, `#content_container` is enough. I think

Comment: Both examples work nicely. Thank you. Could you explain why it didn't work before? I am lost.

Comment: @Radek: your code uses direct event handler. The event handler is attached directly to your `#commentform`, when you call `$('#content_container').html`, your DOM objects are replaced with new ones which don't have event handlers.

Comment: @KhanhTO: could you have a look at my new question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/19371848/250422 It must be similar solution but I cannot figure it out. Maybe I didn't even describe what I want as Sparky didn't understand me.... Thank you

Comment: @Radek, you've split your question into two postings and left critical information out of the other.  Each question should be "self-contained" and not rely on another to make sense.

Comment: @Sparky: Not sure what you mean. 1) This was the first question. I didn't know I was going to do validation after I made this question working. 2) what critical information didn't I provide? In case someone wanted more background I pointed out why things must be done certain way. Meaning that I was able to make validation work by myself but then the ajax submit was broken. All this was in the first version of my second question.

Comment: @Radek, I'm simply referring to two things: 1) that not enough code was provided in the [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371848/submithandler-is-not-triggered-although-it-is-valid)... ajax is cut off and concise markup missing.  2) that according to your comments, looking at this question seems to be required in order to fully understand your other question.  Oh well, no worries.  I'll revisit the other question as time permits.

Comment: @Sparky: well I am learning all the time. So I am happy if you point out how I can make my questions better. Directly under this question is request for html sample. The accepted answer didn't need html. I don't understand exactly what is going on and I thought that html is not needed. I still believe that :-) Thank you for helping (me) out ....

Comment: @Radek, I like to see markup to 1) make sure there are no selecting errors and 2) to make less work for me when I construct a working demo.   With what was provided, I can only post an answer with general recommendations.  Again,  maybe later as time permits.

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly with: [jQuery binding click to a link after AJAX call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842119/jquery-binding-click-to-a-link-after-ajax-call)

You must bind a button to click/submit event in `success` callback.

you can to do:

```
success: function(response) {
      response_from_json = JSON.parse(response);

      $('#content_container').html(response_from_json['html']);
      commentform=$('#commentform');

      $('#commentform').bind("submit", function() { ... } );
}
```